# Calculation of the relative sales index in Spotfire compared to sales in 1 selected base plan

Tags: spotfire

I have got the following data in Spotfire for which I would like to show the relative index of the sales per product compared with a selected base plan.

[image]

As shown in the picture above it is possible to calculate the index relative to the previous plan with the following over statement:

```
100 * (Sum([Sales]) - Sum([Sales]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.Columns]))) / 
Sum([Sales]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.Columns]))
```

However this solution has the following three shortcomings:

1. It compares all sales with the sales in the previous plan instead of one base plan. Changing the OVER statement to use the FirstNode doesn't always work because the data in the real application is imported from the database based upon a query. This results in the value of the FirstNode not always being available.
2. The ordering of the plans is based upon the string value instead of the plan number (second character in the plan name).
3. The base plan is not selectable. In the real application a document property "SelectedPlan" is created (containing the selected value in a drop down list).

So how is it possible to calculate the relative sales index compared to the sales of 1 selected base plan?

Comment: why not just `over ([Product])` versus trying to hack the order of your data? Your `FIRST NODE` problem will be replicated with `MAX` and most aggregations without using a row number feature. Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research we have found a working solution:

```
100 * (Sum([Sales]) / Sum(If([Plan] = '${SelectedPlan}',[Sales],0)) OVER All([Axis.Columns]))
```